# Multi Primary Keys in Android SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, syntax, null, primary-key

In SQLite for Android what is the correct way to add multi primary keys?

Currently I have:

```
String Create_table = "CREATE TABLE project ( keyId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, keyName TEXT PRIMARY KEY)";
```

The alternative method I thought of was:

```
   String Create_table = "CREATE TABLE project (keyID INTEGER, keyName TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(keyID, keyName))";
```

Are both valid? If so, which is better? Also how do I disallow NULL values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No it's not possible to create multiple primary keys for a single table. It's basic rule of any SQL. However you can use other constraint like **UNIQUE** with index to achieve this.

This won't be valid SQL Syntax:

> String Create_table = "CREATE TABLE project ( keyId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, keyName TEXT PRIMARY KEY)";

In other way you can create primary key for multiple column as follows:

```
Create Table yourTableName (col1, col2, col3, PRIMARY KEY (col1, col2));
```

> How do I disallow **NULL** values?

you can use **NOT NULL** Constraint , it will not allow you to enter **NULL** values.

Comment: Can we get one of the column from primary key column as autoincrement

Answer (score -1):

You may use one primary key , more foreign keys in one table